# Can we have a scroll bar for div tag on the ngDialog popup in angualrjs?

Tags: angularjs

I open a popup using ngDialog.Now i want to expand textboxes more .but the popup is expanding according to textboxes.But i need only a div part to be scrolled on the popup in which in div we are expanding textboxes.Is it possible.if possible can anyone help me to solve.

```
//js file

$scope.radiolabels=[];
    $scope.addradio=function(){
        ngDialog.open({
            template:"popupfiles/radioname.html",
            closeByDocument:false,
            closeByEscape:false,
            scope: $scope,
            showClose:false
        });
    };
    $scope.expndradiolabels=function(){
        $scope.order++;
        var objt={
                Name:"",
                type:"radiobtns",
                rbtn:[{
                          Name:"",
                          order:$scope.order
                      }]
                    };

        $scope.radiolabels.push(objt);
    };
    $scope.cancelradioname=function(){
        ngDialog.closeAll();
    };

//html file

<h3 style="color: #0d7dc1;margin-top: 0px;">Enter the Heading name for RadioButtons</h3>
    <h3>Headings For RadioButons:</h3>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <ul>    
            <li ng-repeat="radiolbs in radiolabels track by $index">
                    Label: <input type="text" id="ral_{{$index}}" data-ng-model="$parent.radiolabels[$index].Name"/><br>
                                RadioButtons {{$index}}: <input type="text" id="rab_{{$index}}"><br>
                                RadioButtons {{$index}}:<input type="text" id="rab_{{$index}}"><button class="btn btn-default">+</button>
            <li>
                <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="expndradiolabels()">Click to add multiple radio headings</button>
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default pull-right" ng-click="saveradioname()">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancelradioname()">Cancel</button>
```

Comment: Please paste your HTML snippet in your question as well

Comment: i have edited the question once see it

Comment: but scroll is showing the scrollbars even if i dont append any textboxes...

Comment: even i have used scroll ,pop is expanding with the arrow symbols aside but not scrolled

Comment: why don't you set the width and height accordingly and see if it helps style="width: 150px;height: 150px;overflow: auto;"

Comment: you can, just define a limited height and overflow:auto.

Comment: Hope your issue got resolved.